# Plotting the results of GLM in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, generalized-linear-model, scatterplot

I have this data plotted as a scatter plot in Excel:

[image]

I had done a regression in Excel, and the p value was 2.14E-05 while the R- value was 0.32. I was told the R value was too low compared to the significance of the p value, and was told to control for the dispersion of the data by running it through R with GLM with quasipoisson error.

This gave me

```
glm(formula = encno ~ temp, family = quasipoisson(link = log), 
    data = encnotemp)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-6.008  -2.431  -1.021   1.353   9.441  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 2.005807   0.174628  11.486  < 2e-16 ***
temp        0.029065   0.006528   4.453 1.53e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for quasipoisson family taken to be 10.19898)

    Null deviance: 1807.4  on 171  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1620.1  on 170  degrees of freedom
AIC: NA

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

How do I analyse this output?

The problem is that the scatterplot data is too dispersed, and I would like to make a scatterplot from the quasipoisson GLM output that shows less dispersed (more fitted) data points. Will this be possible?

Comment: .Do you have exact zeros?

Comment: Simulation from the fitted glm indicates that the quasi model doesn't describe the spread of the data well; the variance function doesn't increase quickly enough.

Answer (score 10):

"*I was told the R value was too low compared to the significance of the p value*" -- sounds like nonsense to me.

On the other hand, some form of glm may be a good idea (but it looks to me like the spread may be increasing more than you might expect with a quasipoisson).

Note that nothing about the glm changes the spread of the data -- it only models changing spread (in a particular way). The data are still the data and if you plot them will still look as they do.

You can change the *appearance* of the data via a transformation. One that approximately stabilizes variance when the Poisson parameter is not very small is $\sqrt{y}$. If the Poisson parameter can take small values, you may like to try $\sqrt{y+\frac{3}{8}}$ or $\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{y+1}$ instead (it looks to me like that might well be the case that you have small values).

On the other hand, one that would linearize your fitted model would be a log (but that's only suitable if you don't have exact zeros).

--

Although it won't be satisfying to you, you can plot the fitted curve via

```
plot(temp,encno,xlim=c(0,60))
newdat <- data.frame(temp=seq(9,48,.5))
encnoglm1 <- glm(formula = encno ~ temp, family = quasipoisson(link = log), 
                     data = encnotemp)
fit <- predict(encnoglm1,newdata=newdat,type="response")
lines(fit~temp,data=newdat,type="l",col=4)
```

Or if you want to look at what would be a nearly constant variance if the quasipoisson were suitable:

```
 plot(temp,sqrt(encno+3/8),xlim=c(0,60))
 lines(sqrt(fit+3/8)~temp,data=newdat,type="l",col=2)
```

Comment: It would be useful if whoever thinks my answer is wrong could post a comment so that I can see about improving it.

Comment: Great thank you for your reply :)
I think the r value being too low was meaning that the r value (slope of the trendline) was not significant enough (apparently anything under or around 0.3 is very weak correlation) even though the p value is high. So I am not really sure what is going on here.
I have tried plotting a log transformed data in R but still got a plot showing weak trend and data points that were highly spread out everywhere, but then there are a few exact zeros in the dependent variable data which I should probably fix before trying to log transform again.

Comment: A low $R^2$ -- even a *zero* $R^2$ doesn't indicate a bad model. You can get zero $R^2$ with the exact model that generated the data. Conversely a very high $R^2$ doesn't indicate that the model is suitable. Actually Cosma Shalizi (among others, including many people who answer here) says pretty much the same stuff I tell people -- take a read from p17 [here](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/mreg/15/lectures/10/lecture-10.pdf)

Comment: If you have exact zeros I'd avoid the log. If you want to fix the spread in the plot one of the square root ones should work fairly well, and you can still plot the fitted curve from the glm on it.

Comment: Oh I should clarify that the r value Im talking about is the correlation coefficient r, not the r squared value. I think the correlation coefficient is how much the data relate to one another, so pretty much the slope of the trendline?
Great thank you I will try the square root transform :)

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you're talking about the correlation between data and fit or its square, since the same arguments apply. But the slope of the line is not the same as the correlation (at least not unless you standardize your variables).